# JavaScript смена языка на сайте

Tags: javascript, cookie, localstorage, href, location

У сайта есть 2 версий: 
/ - ru
/en - en
Если пользователь выбрал en, то я делаю редирект
window.location.href = `domain/en`;
Но как мне выводить остальные страницы с помощью JS.
Да, вы можете сказать замени url на относительный путь этой директорий, но у меня есть другие страницы с en версией, которые не относятся к этой папке (profile - profile/en, admin - admin/en).  Я думаю, сделать через localStorage, т.е сохранить статус и проверять на каждой странице, если en == 1, то делать редирект на эти страницы с версткой en версий. Это нормально так делать или же все таки можно проще?

Comment: у Вас `SSR` или `SPA`?

Comment: А у вас там совсем разная верстка или просто локализация ?

Comment: @Lukas для каждой директорий со страницами - 2 версий языка одинаковой версткой

Comment: Посылает человек ссылку другу, а там язык другой

Comment: Поищи какую нить библиотеку типа: I18next, jQuery.I18n, Globalize, Polyglot